# Function that takes variable number of typed args and a closure with same number of typed args?

Tags: kotlin

I'd like to make a function that takes a variable number of arguments of different types, and a closure, and call the closure with the same number of arguments, each corresponding to a type in the original argument list:

```
fun <A, B, ...>mergeWhenValid(
    arg1: Either<Problem, A>,
    arg2: Either<Problem, B>,
    ...,
    closure: (A, B, ...) -> T
): Either<Problem, T> {
    // do stuff and call closure(a, b, ...)
}
```

How might I accomplish this?

Comment: I'm not sure you can have dynamic types like that, unless you write a generator which generates all the permutations from <A> to <A, ..., Z>
Maybe Arrow Meta can do that generation for you

Comment: Do you have any examples of something like this using Arrow Meta?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Easiest might be to write Kotlin / Java code that literally generates the permutations of text in your Stack Overflow question's code, outputs it to a .kt file and then tie it into a Gradle task / Maven plugin. This way you are writing code that writes the boilerplate code for you and then automate the running of that boilerplate generation via Gradle / Maven.
I was thinking that you could use varargs if you are less strict with the types, but that won't work for the `closure: (vararg args: Any)` <- `unsupported modifier on parameter in function`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `mergeWhenValid` just returns `closure` result if all `eithers` are right and `firstProblem.left()` otherwise, you should use `Either.fx<Problem, T>` instead of your function. Example:

```
Either.fx<Problem, String> { "${eitherInt.bind()} ${eitherDouble.bind()} ${eitherFloat.bind()}" }
```

If your logic is more complex and you need somehow handle all `eithers`, you can do it either by creating special merging DSL:

```
fun <R> mergeWhenValid(block: MergeWhenValidScope.() -> R): R = MergeWhenValidScope().block()

class EitherProblem<out T>(internal val either: Either<Problem, T>)

class MergeWhenValidScope {
    private val eithers = mutableListOf<Either<Problem, *>>()

    operator fun <T> Either<Problem, T>.component1(): EitherProblem<T> {
        eithers += this
        return EitherProblem(this)
    }

    private fun doStuff(): Option<Problem> {
        // you can use `eithers` here and choose one of their problems or create a new one
        // if you return None, it will assume that all `eithers` are right,
        // otherwise, problem will be wrapped in Either and returned
        return eithers.asSequence().mapNotNull { it.swap().getOrElse { null } }.firstOption()
    }

    fun <R> combine(block: CombinerScope.() -> R): Either<Problem, R> =
        doStuff().map { it.left() }.getOrElse { CombinerScope.block().right() }

    object CombinerScope {
        operator fun <T> EitherProblem<T>.invoke() = either.getOrHandle {
            error("Unexpected problem $it")
        }
    }
}
```

Use case:

```
mergeWhenValid {
    val (int) = eitherInt
    val (double) = eitherDouble
    val (float) = eitherFloat
    combine { "${int()} ${double()} ${float()}" }
}
```

Or by pipelining functions which add all your `eithers` to some object:

```
fun <T> mergeWhenValid() = MergeWhenValidInit<T>()

class MergeWhenValidInit<T> {
    operator fun <A> invoke(either: Either<Problem, A>): MergeWhenValid<A, T, T> =
        MergeWhenValid(either, listOf(either)) { it }
}

class MergeWhenValid<A, B, C>(
    private val either: Either<Problem, A>,
    private val eithers: List<Either<Problem, *>>,
    private val previous: (B) -> C // is allowed to be called only if all `eithers` are right
) {
    private fun doStuff(): Option<Problem> {
        // you can use `eithers` here and choose one of their problems or create a new one
        // if you return None, it will assume that all `eithers` are right,
        // otherwise, problem will be wrapped in Either and returned
        return eithers.asSequence().mapNotNull { it.swap().getOrElse { null } }.firstOption()
    }

    operator fun invoke(block: (A) -> B): Either<Problem, C> =
        doStuff().map { it.left() }.getOrElse { requireC(block).right() }

    operator fun <D> invoke(either: Either<Problem, D>): MergeWhenValid<D, (A) -> B, C> =
        MergeWhenValid(either, eithers + either) { next -> requireC(next) }

    private fun requireC(next: (A) -> B): C = previous(next(either.getOrHandle {
        error("Unexpected problem $it")
    }))
}
```

Use case:

```
mergeWhenValid<String>()(eitherInt)(eitherDouble)(eitherFloat)() { float ->
    { double -> { int -> "$int $double $float" } }
}
```

Note: the last approach reverses the order of arguments and also forces you to write `{ c -> { b -> { a -> ... } } }` instead of `{ c, b, a -> ... }`.